# I'm having problem of not being defined in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, project

This is my app.js code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import AddContact from "./AddContact";
import ContactList from "./ContactList";
function App() {
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) ?? []
  );
const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts, { id: uuid(), ...contact }]);
  };
const removeContactHandler = (id) => {
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
      return contact.id !== id;
    });
setContacts(newContactList);
  };
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);
return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Header />
      <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} getContactId={removeContactHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my ContactList.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard";

const ContactList = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  const deleteContactHandler = (id) => {
    props.getContactId(id);
  };

  const renderContactList = props.contacts.map((contact) => {
    return (
      <ContactCard
        contact={contact}
        clickHandler={deleteContactHandler}
        key={contact.id}
      />
    );
  });

  return <div className="ui celled list">{ContactList}</div>;
};

export default ContactList;
```

ERROR

[eslint]
src\components\conatctList.js
Line 8:16:  'contactList' is not defined  no-undef

src\components\contactList.js
Line 16:38:  'rendercontactList' is not defined  no-undef
Line 19:16:  'contactList' is not defined        no-undef

I'm currently in learning phase and trying to do some projects but currently stuck at this problem so expecting that someone will help me..

Comment: I hope in `ContactList.js`, you wanted to call `renderContactList()` inside `<div>` instead of rendering `ContactList`.

Comment: did you fixed your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misunderstood how to render a react component. You are returning here `ContactList` recursively which is, I think, not what you are looking for. Please try:

```js
import React from "react"
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard"

const ContactList = (props) => {
  const deleteContactHandler = (id) => {
    props.getContactId(id)
  };

  return (
    <div className="ui celled list">
      {props.contacts.map((contact) => (
        <ContactCard
          contact={contact}
          clickHandler={deleteContactHandler}
          key={contact.id}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactList
```